# $L_2\cap L_\infty$ Banach space - proof check

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Problem:**
$$X=L_2((1,\infty))\cap L_\infty((1,\infty))$$
$$\|x\|=\max\{\|x\|_2,\|x\|_\infty\}$$
Show $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is Banach space.

**Attempt:**

In Banach space every cauchy sequence converges:
$$\|f_n-f_m\|=\max\{\|f_n-f_m\|_2,\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty\}<\varepsilon$$
$$ \Rightarrow\|f_n-f_m\|_2<\varepsilon\ \mathrm{and}\ \|f_n-f_m\|_\infty<\varepsilon$$
This means that $(f_n)$ converges in $(L_2,\|\cdot\|_2)$ and $(L_\infty,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$, because they are both Banach spaces.

The convergence in L spaces implies:
$$\exists (f_{n_k})\subset (f_n), f_1\in L_2:\ |f_{n_k}-f_1|<\varepsilon$$
$$\exists (f_{n_k})\subset (f_n), f_2\in L_\infty:\ |f_{n_j}-f_2|<\varepsilon$$

I know, that I can have $|f_{n_k}-f_{n_j}|<\varepsilon$, so using the triangle inequality:
$$|f_1-f_2|=|(f_1-f_{n_k})-(f_2-f_{n_j})+(f_{n_k}-f_{n_j})|<|f_{n_k}-f_1|+|f_{n_j}-f_2|+|f_{n_k}-f_{n_j}|<3\varepsilon$$
so $|f_1(x)-f_2(x)|<\varepsilon\ \forall x\in(1,\infty) \mathrm{(almost)}$.

Is my proof correct? Is it missing something? I think the final result should be $f_1=f_2$, not just that they are near.

Comment: As $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, $f_1=f_2$.

Comment: How do you prove it?

Comment: If $f_1\neq f_2$ then there would be $\epsilon>0$ such that $\|f_1-f_2\|\geq\epsilon$.  There is not.

Comment: thank you, I already got that. didn't think of contradiction at first